# How to make a button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Just trying to learn here. How would I compare if a person selected "Sign in" from the selection? Currently it sleeps even though I selected "Sign in"

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
from time import sleep

def selectMode():
    if w == vlist[1]:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        sleep(10)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x600")

label_1 = Label(root, text="Hello, world")
label_1.pack()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
 
vlist = ["Create an Account", "Sign In", "Forgot Username or Password"]
 
Combo = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = vlist, width="50")
Combo.set("Pick an Option")
Combo.pack(padx = 5, pady = 150)


   
    w = Button (root, command=selectMode)
    w.pack(padx = 5, pady =5)
            

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `w` is a tk.Button object and `vlist` if full of strings so `w` will never equal `vlist[1]` so `selectMode` will always sleep

Comment: you should check value selected in `Combo`, not in `Button`  - `if Combo.get() == vlist[1]:`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check value selected in `Combo`, not `Button`

```
if Combo.get() == vlist[1]:
```

---

Full working code with other changes.

You can use `root.destroy()` to close window - and then you can run other code (ie. other window) after `root.mainloop()`

```
import time
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions

def select_mode():
    if combo.get() == vlist[1]:
        root.destroy()  # close window
    else:
        time.sleep(10)

# --- main ---   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions

vlist = ["Create an Account", "Sign In", "Forgot Username or Password"]

# ---

# --- main ---

vlist = ["Create an Account", "Sign In", "Forgot Username or Password"]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
  
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=vlist, width="50")  # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
combo.set("Pick an Option")
combo.pack(padx=15, pady=15)  # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
   
w = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=select_mode)
w.pack(padx=15, pady=15)  # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces

root.mainloop()

print('after closing window')  # here you can run another window (with with another mainloop)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)